# order form - replace NaN with 0

Tags: javascript

i need to create an order form just with javascript and have to fill some empty fields with "0" so i don't get a NaN at the final summation.

the problem is, that order form is a typo3 template so i can't fill the fields in advance. my idea was to convert the NaN fields at the final summation into an integer 0 and keep the values which have been altered by the customer.

so, the complete code looks like this, but i think the only questionable part is at the end the add function:

```
<pre>var arrPRICES = ["0", "1.99", "2.99", "3.99", "4.99", "5.99", "6.99", "7.99", "8.99", "9.99"];
function changeInput(objSel, strName){
objSel.form.elements[strName].value = arrPRICES[objSel.selectedIndex];
}


 function cal() {
  var ep01 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ep01").value);
  var stk01 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("stk01").value);
  var gb01 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp01").value = stk01 * ep01).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gp01").value = gb01;
}

 function calc() {
  var ep02 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ep02").value);
  var stk02 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("stk02").value);
  var gb02 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp02").value = stk02 * ep02).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gp02").value = gb02;
}

 function calcu() {
  var ep03 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ep03").value);
  var stk03 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("stk03").value);
  var gb03 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp03").value = stk03 * ep03).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gp03").value = gb03;
 }

  function calcul() {
  var ep04 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ep04").value);
  var stk04 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("stk04").value);
  var gb04 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp04").value = stk04 * ep04).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gp04").value = gb04;
 }

  function calcula() {
  var ep05 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ep05").value);
  var stk05 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("stk05").value);
  var gb05 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp05").value = stk05 * ep05).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gp05").value = gb05;
 }

 function calculat() {
  var ep06 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ep06").value);
  var stk06 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("stk06").value);
  var gb06 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp06").value = stk06 * ep06).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gp06").value = gb06;
 }

 function calculati() {
  var ep07 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ep07").value);
  var stk07 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("stk07").value);
  var gb07 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp07").value = stk07 * ep07).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gp07").value = gb07;
 }

  function calculatio() {
  var ep08 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ep08").value);
  var stk08 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("stk08").value);
  var gb08 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp08").value = stk08 * ep08).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gp08").value = gb08;
 }

 function calculation() {
  var ep09 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ep09").value);
  var stk09 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("stk09").value);
  var gb09 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp09").value = stk09 * ep09).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("gp09").value = gb09;
 }

function add(gp01,gp02,gp03,gp04,sum1,summe01) {
  var gp01 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp01").value);
  if (parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp02").value = ""))
    var gp02 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp02").value = '0');
    } else {
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp02").value);
    }
  if (parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp03").value = ""))
    var gp03 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp03").value = '0');
    } else {
    var gp03 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp03").value);
    }
if (parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp04").value = ""))
    var gp04 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp04").value = '0');
    } else {
    var gp04 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp04").value);
    }
if (parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp05").value = ""))
    var gp05 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp05").value = '0');
    } else {
    var gp05 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp05").value);
    }
if (parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp06").value = ""))
    var gp06 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp06").value = '0');
    } else {
    var gp06 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp06").value);
    }
if (parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp07").value = ""))
    var gp07 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp07").value = '0');
    } else {
    var gp07 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp07").value);
    }
if (parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp08").value = ""))
    var gp08 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp08").value = '0');
    } else {
    var gp08 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp08").value);
    }
if (parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp09").value = ""))
    var gp09 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp09").value = '0');
    } else {
    var gp09 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp09").value);
    }
  var sum1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("summe01").value = gp01 + gp02 + gp03 + gp04 + gp05 + gp06 + gp07 + gp08 + gp09).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("summe01").value = sum1;
}
</pre>
```

before the version above i had the following add function inserted, but the calculation only works when all fields have values entered:

```
<pre>
    function add(gp01,gp02,gp03,gp04,sum1,summe01) {
  var gp01 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp01").value);
  var gp02 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp02").value);
  var gp03 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp03").value);
  var gp04 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp04").value);
  var gp05 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp05").value);
  var gp06 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp06").value);
  var gp07 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp07").value);
  var gp08 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp08").value);
  var gp09 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gp09").value);
  var sum1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("summe01").value = gp01 + gp02 + gp03 + gp04 + gp05 + gp06 + gp07 + gp08 + gp09).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("summe01").value = sum1;
}
</pre>
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: `var gp0X = parseFloat(...) || 0;` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it in a couple of ways:

1. Create a function that does the string-to-number conversion, and handle the `""` case:

   ```
   function parse(str) {
       return str == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(str);
   }
   ```

   Then just use that instead of using `parseFloat` directly:

   ```
   var ep01 = parse(document.getElementById("ep01").value);
   ```

   That still gives you `NaN` if the value isn't blank but cannot be converted to a number.
2. Use JavaScript's [curiously powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

   ```
   var ep01 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ep01").value) || 0;
   ```

   How that works: If `parseFloat` results in `NaN` (or `0`), `0` is used. If `parseFloat` results in any number other than `0`, the number is used. In JavaScript, `||` doesn't result in `true` or `false` like the logical OR operator in many languages, but instead results in the left-hand value if it's "truthy" or the right-hand value if the left-hand value is "falsey." In JavaScript, "falsey" values are `0`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`; all other values are "truthy".

   That gives you `0` **both** for blank fields, and for fields that aren't blank but can't be converted to a number.

   And of course, you can wrap it up in a function to avoid verbosity if you like:

   ```
   function parse(str) {
       return parseFloat(str) || 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a hint, you can greatly simplify your code using a fieldset or other element to contain the inputs you want to total. Then you can put as many or few elements in the fieldset as you want, e.g.

```
<form>
  <fieldset name="set0">
    <input name="i0">0<br>
    <input name="i1">1<br>
    <input name="i2">2<br>
    <input name="i3">3<br>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="text" readonly name="total"><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="calcTotal(this);" value="Get total">
</form>

<script>
  function calcTotal(el) {
    var form = el.form;
    var set = form.set0.elements;
    var total = 0;

    for (var i=0, iLen=set.length; i<iLen; i++) {

      // Borrowing from TJ's answer
      total += parseFloat(set[i].value) || 0;
    }
    form.total.value = total;
  }
</script>
```

The above takes advantage of the fieldset's [*elements* collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-fieldset-elements). You may not like what it does to the form, but you can change that with CSS if you want, or use some other element in a similar way.

Comment: thank you too! i'll have a look if i have to change it more often in future, than i'll create it with the fieldset. thanks!